Troubleshooting Authorization Errors When Accessing a login with google
Error message
I tried to integrate login with Google in a flutter with Firebase and Supabase. it showed me the same error:
Access blocked: Authorization Error
@.com
We cannot verify the authenticity of this app. Please contact the developer. Token failed.
If you are a developer of ****, see error details.
Error 400: invalid_request

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
